# Image is not centered when browser resizes

Tags: html, css, image

Whenever I resize the browser window, this image is not centered horizontally.

Here is a screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/7uvq2y

html:

```
<div class="iPad">
<div class="text"> </div>
<div class="device"> </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.text {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.device {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you provide the real HTML please?

Comment: Where is the image in your code? Is it `.device`'s background image?

Comment: provide full html and even a jsfiddle would be amazing :)

Comment: I can only assume that since you are centering an image, it has a fixed width and the image is still being 'centered' (centering in the browser occurs from the left margin), which means that the image is too large for the container and the image's centered position is at `margin-left:0` since the image's width is greater than the container's width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uuapr1q3/1/  - Here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center align the content an position them in a specific way. You should make the position of the parent div relative and the children element should be positioned absolute. This way the image will always be horizontally centred even when the width of the parent container changes dynamically.

```
.iPad {
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.device {
 position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.device img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Check out this codepen : http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/zGJOJg

Comment: I've tried making the position of the parent relative, and the child's position absolute, but this is what happens:
http://prntscr.com/7uvz0v

Comment: Did you add the rest of the css? give the device a max-width and set the image to be 100% width of the parent container and you need to add the rest of th css.